# What is this statue in Ancient Agora of Athens?

Tags: identify-this, greece, history, athens

Maybe a God? I think the statue was located at the entrance of the ancient market, but that's an old photograph, so I don't really remember..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general consensus online seems to be that it is a [statue of a giant](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sculptures_of_Athenian_Agora._Athens,_Greece.jpg), used to decorate the facade/entrance of the [Odeon of Agrippa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odeon_of_Agrippa):

[image: Statue of a giant in the Athenian Agora]

Comment: Ah I see. It couldn't be a Triton (son of Poseidon), since it has feet. A Γίγαντας then, thanks! Maybe Thanos from the Avengers :) I don't remember about that Odeon.. With the Odeon of Herodes Atticus nearby, that seems logical.

Comment: @gsamaras  Wikipedia images says the Triton is the One next to it on the right in the picture.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I would agree.